# how to search all words starts match with regular expression character in php?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

I have to search all words from a string with regular expression character in php. i am using `preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $matchWords)`;

but it search all words character in the different position.

e.g suppose string is "India is my country". I have to search i

It should result "India" and "is". Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by the `/(?<!\w)i\w+/` regx it will work

Comment: can you explain the regex pattern?

Comment: yes it's only for i,if you want to find other kind of word than replace i with other character